# ASP.NET c# Rating control - making it one time rating and fixed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i'm trying to follow this example to allow users to rate the seminars they have attended:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ASPNet-AJAX-Rating-Control-inside-GridView-TemplateField-ItemTemplate.aspx

How can i make the rating to be rated by the user only ONCE and display the ratings rated by user? I dont want to let users to change their own rating multiple times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Fruit_Rating table you have to add `UserId`.

```
FruitId | Rating | UserId
```

And before inserting the rating, you have to make a query to see if `UserId` already made an rating on that `Fruit`, if it's true than skip, else make an insert.

Pseudo cod will look like below.

```
var currentRating = GetFruit_RatingBy(RatingId and UserId);
if(currentRating == null) {
     currentRating = new Fruit_Rating(FruitId, newRating, UserId);
     Insert(currentRating);
}
```

If you want that cell to be readonly you can override `RowDataBound` event and write your logic for `readonly` there.

Comment: Is there any ways to convert the rating to be read only(not able fill any stars) once the user has rated that particular row?

Comment: @ags if don't want user to change theyr rating, you can remove the part with update, i update my code only for insert.

Comment: @ags i think it's a little bit difficult to make a specific cell from gridview readonly, the easiest way is to let the code as it is and to skip the update part in code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a select query in the rating table and check it against the `UserID`

query : `SELECT Rating FROM FRUIT_RATING WHERE UserID = @userID`

Take this into a `DataTable` and check if the `DataTable` contains any rows by `dt.Rows.Count` and check if it is `>0` , i.e. if there will be a User who has rated a fruit , then the `FRUIT_RATING` table will have an entry for it , so you disable the textbox by changing the CSS class of it , and for that the CSS you can easily find [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs2.asp).

**AND** if there is no entry in the table that is `dt.Rows.Count == 0` , you make an entry into the table .

I would recommend you to use an `asp:Repeater` control because finding controls in it is easier and is very similar to the `asp:GridView` control. You can find a control in Repeater by :

```
TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)rptr.Items[i].FindControl("txtRating");
```

and then change the CSS class of it by :

```
txtBox.CssClass = "disabled-input";
```